# How can I set the path to my Java decompiler in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, path

I am relatively new to stack overflow, VSCode, and programming. I am using a Mac. I downloaded VSCode for use with Python around two months ago. I can not run my code in VSCode but I enjoyed working in VSCode so I would write in it and run my code outside of it. Now I have the same issue with Java. I can not "solve," this in the same way because I do not know how I can run my Java code outside of an IDE.

I first read the instructions for setting up VSCode for Java on VSCodes website. I followed the instructions but when I tried to run a, "Hello world," program it said I did not have a debugger. I re-installed Redhat's Java support, closed and re-opened VSCode, and tried to run it again. This time it said java.jdt.Is.home is pointing to a missing or inaccessible folder. I looked this up found one description of this issue from 2018. I had a hard time understanding what it was asking me to do but at my best interpretation I wrote "which java," in Terminal and copy pasted what it returned (usr/bin/java) into settings.json after "java.home: ". This gave me an error stating that it is outdated and I should change it to, "java.jdt.Is.home: " so I did. I also tried adding "local/" between "usr/" and "bin" as it appeared in my path to my Python3 interpreter. All of these gave me the same error when I tried to run a hello world program.[image: The java.jdt.Is.Java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings (/usr/bin/java) does not point to a JDK.][image]What can I do to solve my issue with Java in VSCode?

Comment: Step 1: Install [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) Step 2: `sdk install java` Step 3: Set that to `$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/` -- NOTE: JAVA_HOME contains `bin/java`, it is not the path to `java` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which java` can not get the right java home.

You need to take `/usr/libexec/java_home` or `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`.

Java home on MacOs looks like: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home`

---

**But** You need not set the `"java.jdt.ls.java.home"` at all. Because the JRE has been embedded in the `Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat` extension.
Only the **universal version** without embedded JRE can specify the `java.jdt.ls.java.home` manually. Otherwise, it will search `JDK_HOME` `JAVA_HOME` `current system path`.

You can refer to the [official dosc](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#java-tooling-jdk).

---

So, have you installed the related extensions? You can install [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), which contains the extensions you need.

I am a little confused about why you can not run the python or java codes, it's very rare. After you installed the related extensions([Python Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python-extension-pack)) , just right-click in the editor, you can select the `Run Java` `Debug Java` `Run Python File in Terminal` and so on. Or you can click the button on the top-right.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I have downloaded those extensions and it has not solved my issue, or changed my results at all for testing a program in Python that I know to work outside of VSCode. I am not sure what I have done wrong here still, or how to fix that.
Using the returned string from running " /usr/libexec/java_home" in terminal solved the issue with Java though.